# how to use jquery to select all inputs, that are not submit, reset or button?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, input

I'm trying to select all input elements except input type="submit/reset/button

I have tried to make a selector like this:

```
inputSelector = 'input:not(input[type=button], input[type=submit], input[type=reset]), textarea, select';
```

But this does not work, because the submit buttons always make into the final selection.

Any idea what's wrong with the above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try modifying your selector to chain `.not(...)` like:

```
var inputs = $('input, textarea, select')
                .not(':input[type=button], :input[type=submit], :input[type=reset]');

$(inputs).each(function() {
    console.log(this.type);
});
```

This makes it (arguably) easier to read, and should work how you expect.

Comment: I'm using it in a plugin, so I guess I'm stuck with the crummy selector. still trying...

Answer (score 13):

This answer is arguably harder to read than Michael Robinson's, but I find it more succinct.  Rather than run the `not()` function, you can select for it using `:input` to gather all form elements, then filter with the `:not()` selector for each unwanted input type.

From jQuery's API documentation (https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/):

> The `:input` selector basically selects all form controls.

The "CSS"-like selector version, the `:not()` selectors are separate, and can be used in CSS 3, too:

```
var inputs = $("#theForm").find("input:not([type=button]):not([type=submit]):not([type=reset])");
```

Answer (score 0):

Even shorter, more concise approach:

```
var inputs = $(':input[type!=button]:input[type!=submit]:input[type!=reset]');
```

Or

```
$("#some-selector :input[type!=button]:input[type!=submit]:input[type!=reset]');
```